# Rotating Display on Debian Buster from CLI

Tags: debian, startup, xrandr

I am attempting to run an AvaloniaUI application on a version of Debian(Buster) on an ASUS TinkerBoard. The display I am using is a 7 inch 1920x1080p touchscreen display.

The application runs in a portrait-like mode(i.e. it runs at 1080x1920), so I have been attempting to rotate the display to so that the application can run as such.

Using xrandr to rotate the display has given me very little success. When I execute:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left
```

or

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate right
```

It blanks the screen briefly but has no effect. I am able to invert the screen using the same command, however that doesn't exactly help the issue. I also tried altering the resolution using xrandr and various other commands I had found but have been unsuccessful as of yet.

I have also attempted to add:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate
```

To the /etc/rc.local script. When using 'echo 3', this will actually cause the commands which run on screen at boot to be rotated successfully. However, upon booting into the OS, the display is no longer rotated and is back to being 'landscape' (i.e. 1920x1080). Trying to run it as a shell script or as a service has also been unsuccessful.

I can't seem to find much information online on how else to rotate the display other than the basic 'xrandr' commands. I apologise for my poor explanation, as I am still relatively new to Linux.

Here's the output of:

```
xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 255mm x 255mm

   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1024x600      60.04 +
   1600x900      60.00
   1440x810      59.98
   1360x768      59.80
   1280x720      60.00
   1152x648      60.01
   1024x576      59.97
   800x450       60.05
```

A xrandr command which does what I expect would be:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate inverted
```

This successfully inverts the screen.

Comment: fbcon ("con" is for "console") is not used by your graphical interface, so that's to be expected.

Comment: do `dmesg` or `journalctl -xe` contain any errors after you've tried to use `xrandr`? Can you add the full output listing of `xrandr` (without any arguments) to your quesiton?

Comment: Also add an `xrandr` command that does what you expect, and perhaps the ouput of running `xrandr` without any arguments.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up why fbcon wasn't working for the display. I've added the requested information.

Comment: To answer your question regarding dmesg and journalctl -xe, a couple errors are shown for the former, most notably
[   11.775483] [drm:dw_hdmi_rockchip_set_property] *ERROR* failed to set rockchip hdmi connector property

Comment: Does `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate left` make any difference? (`xrandr` is weird sometimes, but specifying mode and position (even  though the values are quite obvious) sometimes help me, also manipulating one screen at a time have helped me, but that doesn't look to be your problem)

Comment: I tried the command with the additional position parameters, however there seemed to be no difference unfortunately. 
Also thanks to @MarcusMüller for fixing the formatting above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue.
I was able to edit the file within /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ (mine was called "20-modesetting.conf", but I'm not sure everyone's will be).
Within the 'Screen' subsection I added an option for 1080x1920:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Default Screen"
SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080" "1280x1024" "1024x768" "800x600" "1080x1920"
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then below this section I added an additional section 'Monitor' like so:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1"
    Option "PreferredMode" "1080x1920"
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Option "Rotate" "left"
EndSection
```

This forces the desktop to boot in 1080x1920 resolution, while the Rotate option rotates the screen.

Both of these options are required to correctly rotate the screen in portrait mode.

The identifier will be specific to what your input is named, mine was "HDMI-1".

Comment: I should note that this will not rotate the touchscreen on the device as well, however that wasn't the content of this particular question.